# Associate bitbucket to Forge Laravel

Tags: laravel, bitbucket, forge

I can't Associate bitbucket to Forge
I got this Error

## bitbucket.org SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.4

## bitbucket.org SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3

no hostkey alg
Cloning into 'mySite.com'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'Host IP' to the list of known hosts.
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/forge/mySite.com
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

How can I get started??

Comment: Read the error message...

Comment: It's literally written there for you... `"To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file"`